# How to select all the input type in SAP UI 5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have some input tags in my view.xml

```
<CheckBox checked="true" text="dd" id="chkbx_mxzvw" change = "reacxdData" ></CheckBox>
<CheckBox checked="true" text="eEast" id="chkbx_neqrfd" change = "reacxdData" ></CheckBox>
<CheckBox checked="true" text="wre" id="chkczvbx_w" change = "reacxdData" ></CheckBox>
```

Is there any way for me to select all the 3 check box and add an attribute setEnabled('false') in my Controller. I have a view instance in the controller

Generally in jQuery we will do it as $('input').attr('disabled',disabled);
Is there any kind of similar thing in SAP UI 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just bind the `enabled` property to a local model, and by setting that property to `false` it will make any bound control readonly.

```
<CheckBox enabled="{/ui/enabled}" />
<TextInput enabled="{/ui/enabled}" />
etc...
```

Your model then could look like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    ui : {
        enabled : true
    },
    etc....
});
```

To set all controls which have their `enabled` property bound to this model property, simply use:

```
oModel.setProperty("/ui/enabled", false);
```

*On a sidenote, please note `sap.ui.commons` namespace controls are deprecated as of 1.38*